# Convert string to int in C++

Tags: c++, string, integer

I have a string, `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

I am reading the string into a structure of smaller strings, and using substr to parse it. I need to convert one of those string types to integer.

`atoi` is not working for me. How can I do it? It says:

> cannot convert std::string to const char*

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main();
{
    string s = "453"

    int y = atoi(S);
}
```

Comment: `atoi` is not a very good function to use if you need to validate that it successfully converted, something better to use would be `strtol`: [Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

Answer (score 6):

[`std::atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) requires `const char *` to pass in.

Change it to:

```
int y = atoi(s.c_str());
```

or use [`std::stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which you can pass a `string` directly:

```
int y = stoi(s);
```

---

You program has several other errors. Workable code could be something like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "453";
    int y = atoi(s.c_str());
    // int y = stoi(s); // another method
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the case matters. If you declare your string as `s`, you need to use `s`, not `S` when calling it. You are also missing a semicolon to mark the end of the instruction. On top of that, the `atoi` takes `char *` as parameter not a string, so you need to pass in an array of char or a pointer to a char array:

***Function signature:***     `int atoi (const char * str);`

```
string s = "453"; // Missing ';'

int y = atoi(s.c_str());  // Need to use s, not S
```

**Full code:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()    // Get rid of the semicolon here
{
    string s = "453"; // Missing ';'
    int y = atoi(s.c_str());  // Need to use s, not S
    cout << "y =\n";
    cout << y;
    char e;     // This and the below line is just to hold the
                // program and avoid the window/program to
                // close until you press one key.
    cin  >> e;
}
```

Comment: when i write your code this erroe apear error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: you need to include whatever header your atoi function belongs to, and you need to make sure you include header of any function you us. take a look at the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>

int toInt(std::string str)
{
    int num;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    ss >> num;
    return num;
}
```